# listing files works, but how do I list files within folders (VBA, excel)?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code which I found online and it's working great. It lists any files in a specified folder and their properties. I just need to amend this function which returns a list of files. I need it to look in a given path at ALL files. So if it's a folder, open it and return those files too. I eventually need to get this to mark each file (so in a column in excel) where it came from. If it would be possible to create a hirarchy somehow that would be great.... but for now, just opening a folder if it finds on and listing those files would be awesome!

Any help is REALLY appreciated!

```
Private Function fcnGetFileList(ByVal strPath As String, Optional strFilter As String) As Variant
'   Returns a one dimensional array with filenames
'   Otherwise returns False

Dim f As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim FileList() As String

    If strFilter = "" Then strFilter = "*.*" 'can provide an extension to check?

    'set the path
    Select Case Right$(strPath, 1)
     Case "\", "/"
         strPath = Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)
    End Select

    ReDim Preserve FileList(0)

    f = Dir$(strPath & "\" & strFilter)

    Do While Len(f) > 0
        ReDim Preserve FileList(i) As String
        FileList(i) = f
        i = i + 1
        f = Dir$()
    Loop

    If FileList(0) <> Empty Then
        fcnGetFileList = FileList
    Else
        fcnGetFileList = False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: How often do you see yourself doing this?

Comment: Do you really use a "fcn" prefix for all your functions? That's taking Hungarian notation way too far! :-)  [And yet you have a string variable called 'f'...]

Comment: @Remou - the code will be run daily / weekly to run a series of reports to find out document properties etc. 
@Gary - haha, this isn't my code - it's part of some I downloaded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideas:

Add the microsoft scripting runtime And use the file system object (much better file/folder handling)

Make this function recursive, add a vbdirectory parameter to the dir function, and use GetAtrr to get info about each file. If the file is a folder again, call this function again with this new folder.

Comment: I'm doing what you suggested and trying to check if it's a folder - then looping as suggested. Thanks :)